# "semmni" is properly set. (more details) Expected Value : 128 Actual Value : 0

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, centos7

i'm trying to install `Oracle11g`, and this happened, is there a way to fix this?

i had tried to reboot and run the script `runfixup.sh` still can't resolve the problem.

I'm trying to install `Oracle 11gR2` on `Oracle Linux 7.4`.

While the installer is performing prerequisite checks, we are  getting error:

This is a prerequisite condition to test whether the OS kernel parameter `semmni` is properly set.

More details :

> ```
> Expected Value : 128
>
> Actual Value : 0
> ```

Now if I execute as root:

```
/sbin/sysctl -a | grep sem

kernel.sem = 32000      1024000000      500     128
```

Which means that `semmni=128`.

Can somebody tell me what I'm I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

*You need to issue the following command*

```
[root@localhost ~]# /sbin/sysctl -p
```

*the changes to take effect.*

And then the value(*the rightmost one returning below*) might be checked by issuing

```
[root@localhost ~]# more /proc/sys/kernel/sem
32000      1024000000      500     128
```